# How to assign value in generic list without using a for loop

Tags: c#

I have an generic `List` with 7 fields and 15 rows. I would like to assign some default values to field1 and field2 without using a `for` loop. Please advise on how to do this.

```cs
public class TestSetup: BaseModel
{
   public int TestID { get; set; }
   public int StyleStockID { get; set; }
   public int? TypeID { get; set; }
   public int? PartNoID { get; set; }
   public int? ComponentID { get; set; }
   public int? LeatherID { get; set; }
   public int? ColorID { get; set; }          
}
    
protected List<StyleBomLeatherSetup> styleBomLeatherSetups { get; set; } = new List<StyleBomLeatherSetup>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set default value as

```
public int? TypeID { get; set; } = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need a "for loop"? You can just slap an `=` on your properties and assign them a default value.

```
public class TestSetup : BaseModel
{
   public int TestID { get; set; } = 1000; // default value
   public int StyleStockID { get; set; } = 25; // default value
   public int? TypeID { get; set; }
   public int? PartNoID { get; set; }
   public int? ComponentID { get; set; }
   public int? LeatherID { get; set; }
   public int? ColorID { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

You said without `for` loop, but you never said anything about a `foreach` loop, so consider an approach similar to this:

`using System.Reflection;`

```
TestSetup testSetup = new TestSetup();
Type type = testSetup.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
     if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int)) property.SetValue(testSetup, 1000);
}
```

Or if you want to set them individually you can do something like:

```
if (property.Name == "TestID") property.SetValue(testSetup, 1000);
```

Comment: yes,this is correct but i need to set value dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question

If you are looking for a way to populate the list without a loop, you may use an initializer like in the following example

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime Born { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { Name = "Fabio", Born = new DateTime(1975, 01, 23) },
                new Person { Name = "Laura", Born = new DateTime(1985, 07, 07) },
            };

            Console.WriteLine(people.Count);
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I realize I misunderstood your question

If you need to set the properties to a default value, then I cannot think of a better solution than the one that has already been suggested in other answers

```cs
public string Name { get; set; } = "Fabio";
public DateTime Born { get; set; } = new DateTime(1975, 01, 23);
```

**EDIT 2**

The following example uses a constructor instead of an initializer and does not differ much from the previous one, except for the fact that you have to provide values for the properties when you instantiate the class

However, I am not really sure I understand what you aim to achieve. Could you please add more information to your question?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; protected set; }
            public DateTime Born { get; protected set; }

            public Person(string name, DateTime born)
            {
                Name = name;
                Born = born;
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person("Fabio", new DateTime(1975, 01, 23)),
                new Person("Laura", new DateTime(1985, 07, 07)),
            };

            Console.WriteLine(people.Count);
        }

    }
}
```

Fabio

Comment: The above code will work only for first two rows.I need to set default value for all rows

Comment: @Ismail, I realize I misunderstood your question. I will update my answer. The result will be similar to the other answers though

Comment: How can I change default as dynamically,tha above code is static for all rows.I need to pass default value for all record  based on logic

Comment: @Ismail, you may use a constructor. I will update my answer to provide an example. This will not differ much from the example using initializers, though. I am not really sure I understand what you aim to achieve